# Is there a name for a topological space $X$ in which very closed set is contained in a countable union of compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, descriptive-set-theory

Is there a name for a topological space $X$ which satisfies the following condition:

> Every closed set in $X$ is contained in a countable union of compact sets

Does Baire space satisfy this condition?

Thank you!

Comment: The Baire space **clearly** doesn't satisfy that. By your previous question. Remember that the Baire space is closed in itself.

Comment: yes, ok Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This property is equivalent to ***$\sigma$-compactness,*** which says that the space itself is a countable union of compact subsets.  If your property holds for a space $X$, then since $X$ is a closed subspace of itself, it is contained in a countable union of compact subsets. Conversely, if $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, then your property holds because *every* subset is contained in a countable union of compact subsets.

Comment: I see Thank you. As a matter of fact, I meant "Every closed set $A$ in $X$, where $A \neq X$  is contained in a countable union of compact sets".. Should I open another post for it?

Comment: You probably should.  Off the top of my head, I don't know the answer to that one.