# Is there a name for a topological space $X$ in which Every closed subset $A\subsetneq X$ is contained in a countable union of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, terminology, descriptive-set-theory

As was recommended for me in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709880/is-there-a-name-for-a-topological-space-x-in-which-very-closed-set-is-containe#comment1487399_710181) I would like to share the following question with you:
Is there a name for a topological space $X$ which satisfies the following condition:

> Every closed subset $A\subsetneq X$ is contained in a countable union of compact sets

Does Baire space satisfy this condition?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that if the space itself can be written as a union of two closed sets (not even disjoint, just both nonempty) then you get $\sigma$-compactness again.

Comment: Note that any closed $F \subseteq \omega^\omega$ with nonempty interior cannot be covered by countably many compact sets, by the same argument [I used earlier](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/709751/8348).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space $\mathbf{X}$ which is a countable union of compact sets is called a $K_\sigma$-space, and as the intersection of a closed set and a compact set is compact, any closed subspace of a $K_\sigma$-space is $K_\sigma$ again. Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is not $K_\sigma$.

I am a bit puzzled though by the requirement $A \subsetneq \mathbf{X}$ though (rather than $A \subseteq \mathbf{X})$. In case of Baire space this makes no difference, as e.g. $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.